# Barycentric coordinates

Tags: graphics, manipulate, geometry

I am 100% new to mathematica and I don't really understand if I am doing this correctly. I have some most code except the calculation of the color. I will do that once I know I am doing this correctly. I am trying to make sure it is correct and if am not I need some direction as to what I am doing wrong. I added comments if that helps. Anything helps!

```
(* Triangle vertices *)

v1 = {-2.0, -2.0};
v2 = {2.0, -2.0};
v3 = {0.0, 2.0};

(* xy-space to plot *)

c1 = {1, 0, 0};
c2 = {0, 1, 0};
c3 = {0, 0, 1};
```

I am trying to Compute the barycentric coordiantes of a 2D point `xy` based on triangle vertices `v1`, `v2`, `v3`  and that is what I  need help on because I'm not sure that I got it right.

```
(* Input: xy = {x, y} and global v1, v2, v2 each as {x,y} *)
(* Output: uvw = {u, v, w}, the barycentric coordinates *)


(* The entries in the linear system set-up below need set. I Determine what  
   values in function *)

computeBaryCoords[xy_] := (
  mat = {{v1[[1]], v2[[1]], v3[[1]]}, {v1[[2]], v2[[2]], v3[[2]]}, {v1, v2, v3}};
  rhs = {xy[[1]], xy[[2]], mat};
  uvw = LinearSolve[mat, rhs];
  Return[uvw]
  );

computeColor[uvw_] := Return[ (* going to calculate colors *)]; 

range = 4;
plotTriangle = 
  Graphics[
    {EdgeForm[Thick], White, Polygon[{v1, v2, v3}], 
     PointSize[0.05], 
     RGBColor[c1], Point[v1], 
     RGBColor[c2], Point[v2], 
     RGBColor[c3], Point[v3]}, 
    Axes -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-range, range}, {-range, range}}];

Manipulate[(
  uvw = computeBaryCoords[xy];
  rgb = computeColor[uvw];
  plotPoint = 
    Graphics[
      {RGBColor[rgb[[1]], rgb[[2]], rgb[[3]]], PointSize[0.08],  Point[xy]}];
  plotBaryCoords =  
    Graphics[
      {Black 
       Text[Style["Barycentric Coordinates: ", FontSize -> 15], {0, 4}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], 
       Text[Style[NumberForm[uvw, 2], FontSize -> 15], {4, 4}, Scaled[{1, 1}]]}];
  Show[{plotTriangle, plotPoint, plotBaryCoords}]),
  {{xy, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

Comment: Does `computeBaryCoords` work incorrectly? Or is it the `Manipulate` that misbehaves?

Comment: @michaelE2  I had to respost the question becuase I posted as guest and I could not comment on it. Yes I think the problem is in the computerBaryCords

Comment: Please go [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged and regain access to your question.

Answer (score 5):

I tweaked your function slightly:

```
computeBaryCoords[xy_] := With[
    {mat = {{v1[[1]], v2[[1]], v3[[1]]}, {v1[[2]], v2[[2]], v3[[2]]}, {1, 1, 1}}},
    LinearSolve[mat, Append[xy, 1]]
]
```

Basically, your `mat` and `rhs` were not quite right, and one should never use [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return) as the last expression, as it is redundant. Quick check:

```
coords = computeBaryCoords[{1,1}]
coords . {v1, v2, v3}
```

> {-0.125, 0.375, 0.75}
>
> {1., 1.}

However, I think it makes sense to make the dependencies on the vertices explicit, so I would use something like this:

```
BarycentricTransform[{v1_,v2_,v3_}] := TransformationFunction[
    PadRight[
        Inverse @ PadRight[Transpose@{v1,v2,v3}, {3,3}, 1],
        {4,3},
        {{0,0,1}}
    ]
]
```

Here is an example of it in use:

```
bf = BarycentricTransform[{v1, v2, v3}];

bf[{{1,1}, {1,2}, {0, 1}}]
% . {v1,v2,v3}
```

> {{-0.125, 0.375, 0.75}, {-0.25, 0.25, 1.}, {0.125, 0.125, 0.75}}
>
> {{1., 1.}, {1., 2.}, {0., 1.}}

**Update**

Here's an update that works with higher dimensions:

```
BarycentricTransform::nonn1 = "The list of vectors should have equal length, and the number of arguments is expected to be 1 less than their length";

BarycentricTransform[v_List] := Module[{dim=Dimensions[v], res},
    res = If[!MatchQ[dim, {n_, m_} /; m+1 == n], 
        Message[BarycentricTransform::nonn1];
        $Failed,

        With[{mat = Inverse @ PadRight[Transpose @ v, dim + {0, 1}, 1]},
            AffineTransform[{mat[[All, ;;-2]], mat[[All, -1]]}]
        ]
    ];
    res /; !MatchQ[res, $Failed | _AffineTransform]
]
```

An example with dimension 5:

```
SeedRandom[1];
v = RandomReal[10, {5, 4}];
bf = BarycentricTransform[v];

pts = RandomReal[5, {3, 4}];
bf[pts]
```

> {{5.93009, -0.958983, 4.6546, -3.60732, -5.01838}, {-1.13559, 
>     1.21887, -0.129826, 0.174377, 0.872176}, {4.93582, -0.689189, 
>     3.94031, -2.94722, -4.23972}}

Check that the coordinates sum to 1:

```
Total[bf[pts], {2}]
```

> {1., 1., 1.}

Check that the dot product with the vectors reproduces the initial points:

```
bf[pts] . v == pts
```

> True

Comment: Can someone explain how to change the dimension to something other than 5.  I can not get the barycentricTransform function to report true, when say I change 5 to 3 or 6?